# Getting error on Heroku for "Django DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header:" even after adding the url to ALLOWED_HOST

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, django-deployment, heroku-ci

So I'm trying to deploy my django project to heroko, and I got this.

[image: Error message]

I know what is the issue here, so I have added the url `the-yogify.herokuapp.com` to the `ALLOWED_HOST` in the settings.py file of my django project.

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://the-yogify.herokuapp.com/',
'https://the-yogify.herokuapp.com/',
'the-yogify.herokuapp.com',
'the-yogify.herokuapp.com/',
'127.0.0.1']
```

But the error is still persistent.

What am I doing wrong here? I thought the actual error might be something else.

So I printed out the heroku logs, it also shows same error.

```
2020-11-24T04:10:53.978271+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-24 04:10:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-11-24T04:10:53.979367+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-24 04:10:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:25352 (4)
2020-11-24T04:10:53.979552+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-24 04:10:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-11-24T04:10:53.991703+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-24 04:10:53 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-11-24T04:10:54.026534+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-24 04:10:54 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-11-24T04:10:54.200285+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-11-24T04:10:57.847722+00:00 app[web.1]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'the-yogify.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'the-yogify.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2020-11-24T04:10:58.083555+00:00 app[web.1]: Bad Request: /
2020-11-24T04:10:58.092696+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.11.198.97 - - [24/Nov/2020:04:10:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59515 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36 Edg/86.0.622.51"
2020-11-24T04:10:58.099353+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=the-yogify.herokuapp.com request_id=dafb2e9e-fd1c-49d7-8375-fb0b707ef5bc fwd="42.111.13.118" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2796ms status=400 bytes=59767 protocol=https
2020-11-24T04:10:59.830985+00:00 app[web.1]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'the-yogify.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'the-yogify.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

For some more trouble shooting you could see if it runs with the heroku local command:

```
heroku local
```

We'd expect to encounter this DisallowedHost error here.  Now add '0.0.0.0' to your ALLOWED_HOSTS:

**settings.py**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '0.0.0.0',
    'the-yogify.herokuapp.com', # your herokuapp url
    '127.0.0.1'
]
```

If this works then it might be as simple as you're not pushing the changes to your heroku server?

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Changed ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py"
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, problem is I'm on window... so `heroku local` wouldn't run, as I'm using gunicorn, and gunicorn nowadays uses `fcntl` which does not have any support for windows.

Comment: It should be ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '0.0.0.0',
    'the-yogify.herokuapp.com',
    '127.0.0.1'
]. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it was my bad.

I found that there are 2 `settings.py` file in my django project. One was in the project root dir and another one inside `<project name>/`.
And I've been making all the changes to the root `setting.py`.
I still have absolutely no idea, how and when another setting.py file was created.
And finally as suggested by the error messages, I fixed the issue and all is fine.

Thanks to everyone for their responses.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add `*` in `ALLOWED_HOST` in settings.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
   '*',
   'http://the-yogify.herokuapp.com/',
   'https://the-yogify.herokuapp.com/',
   'the-yogify.herokuapp.com',
   'the-yogify.herokuapp.com/',
   '127.0.0.1',
]
```

It will tell django to serve all hosts.

Comment: surprisingly its showing the same exact error. Not even a single letter is changed. :(

Comment: So I'm starting to thing even the error message is about allowed hosts, but the actual problem is somewhere else.

Comment: And for security purposes, this solution is not recommended even if it would have worked.

Comment: Ok listen, remove the rest of the hosts that you added in `ALLOWED_HOST` and just keep the `*`. Try it.

Comment: this is so weird... I know.